# Running my Java code to access ICOBench API I am getting HTTP Error 403

Tags: java

I tried to get the ICObench website example code working in Java, but I am getting an HTTP403. I am not sure if the data object is passed to the server properly. Unfortunately, I am not getting any hint from the server of what I could have done wrong.

```
public static String private_key = "...";
public static String public_key = "...";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Mac sha384_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA384");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(private_key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA384");
    sha384_HMAC.init(secretKeySpec);

    String data = "{}";
    String encoded_64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha384_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
    String result = sendPost("https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/trending", data, encoded_64);

    System.err.println(">>> " + result);
}

public static String sendPost(String url, String data, String sign) throws Exception {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    try {
        System.err.println("signed message : " + sign + " " + data);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + data.length());
        con.setRequestProperty("X-ICObench-Key", public_key);
        con.setRequestProperty("X-ICObench-Sig", sign);
        con.setDoOutput(data != null);

        if (data != null) {
            OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
            wr.write(data.getBytes());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        }

        System.err.println(con.getResponseMessage());

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);
        }
        return response.toString();
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint from the server: Request was accepted, but access is denied.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I was looking for "more" clues, of course 403 means access denied but this doesn't help me in this case...